# Some controls are not stretching

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In this window I have many different controls and I want to stretch which is possible
but there are some controls by 'stackGroup', 'listBox1', 'listBox2' that don't stretching.. Why ??
Also is this way i right to do this kind of pages

```
<Window x:Class="TwoColumnGridSample.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="Window1" Height="759" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,95">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="509"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="111"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="472" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="165" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,163">
                <ListBox Name="listBox1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Width="165" ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding .}" Click="Button_Click"  Style="{StaticResource  listboxbuttons}"></Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="stackGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Height="457" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="460" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="24" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="316"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image x:Name="imageMap" Source="Resources/images.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Fill" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
                    <Border  BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="1,1,1,1" Margin="2,4,0,17" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="3,3,3,3">
                            <GroupBox Header="Club Badge" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="123" Width="134"/>
                            <GroupBox Header="Goalie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="179" Width="134" Margin="0,128,0,0"/>
                            <GroupBox Header="Defender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="307" Width="134"/>
                            <GroupBox Header="MidFielder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="278,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="307" Width="134"/>
                            <GroupBox Header="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="307" Width="155"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ProgressBar BorderBrush="#FF6081B0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="2,303,0,43" Value="45" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="#FF6081B0" Grid.RowSpan="2"  />
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <ListBox Height="96" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="listBox2" Width="782" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="30 0 30 0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Vertical Item 1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Vertical Item 2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Vertical Item 3" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Vertical Item 4" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Vertical Item 5" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: in which direction they don't stretch width or height?

Comment: stackGroup works only for left and right directions but doesn't work for bottom direction. listbox1 and listbox2 don't work to no one direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same answer as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27274438/wpf-grid-horizontalalignment-doesnt-work-sizes-dont-changes/27274888#27274888). StackPanel will not respect stretch alignments in the same direction as its orientation. So a StackPanel whose orientation is vertical will not respect a VerticalAlignment of stretch for a child.

listBox1 doesn't stretch because it's VerticalAlignment is stretch and it's container StackPanel has an orientation of Vertical (that's its default). You could change that StackPanel to be horizontal, replace it with another container (such as a DockPanel), or remove it entirely since it only contains one element.

Similar reasoning can be applied to your other issues